# Leer Matriz Json en Java usando Gson

Tags: java, json, array, matrices, gson

tengo la siguiente duda sobre el siguiente bloque de código.... Resulta que cuando tengo este Json  el método si lo lee correctamente.
//Json que lee correctamente
**

```
{
    "Tamaño": 0,
    "Nombre": "A",
    "Sexo": "A",
    "Usuario": "A",
    "Contraseña": "A"
  }
```

**
//Bloque de código para leer Json Anterior
**

```
public boolean Validad_Ingreso()
{
    boolean Condicion =  false;
    Object F[];
    Properties L;        
    Leer_Archivo();
    Usuario  P=  Usuario.getInstancia();
    F = new Object[Vec_J.size()];          
    for (int i = 0; i < Vec_J.size(); i++) {
        F[i] =Vec_J.get(i);
        L =Json.fromJson(Vec_J.get(i), Properties.class);           
        if(P.getUsuario().equals(L.get("Usuario")) && P.getContraseña().equals(L.get("Contraseña"))){                       
            Condicion =  true;
            P.setNombre(L.get("Nombre")+"");
            P.setSexo(L.get("Sexo")+"");
            break;
        }    
    }    
    return Condicion;
}
```

**
El bloque de código anterior lee el Json anterior sin ningún problema, pero cuando tengo el Json de la siguiente manera, no lee nada
//Json nuevo que no lee
**

```
{
    "Tamaño": 1,
    "Mov": [
      null
    ],
    "Partidas": [
      null
    ],
    "Duracion": [
      "2"
    ],
    "Nombre": "Andres",
    "Sexo": "M",
    "Usuario": "AR",
    "Contraseña": "12"
  }
```

**
// los valores null son porque aun no se les ha asignado valores

Si alguien sabe, le agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví el problema...
El bloque de código quedo de la siguiente manera.

```
public boolean Validad_Ingreso()
{
    boolean Condicion =  false;       
    Leer_Archivo();    // este Método retorna los valores que hay en el Json, es decir lee el archivo Json.
    Usuario  P=  Usuario.getInstancia();    
    for (int i = 0; i < Vec_J.size(); i++) {        
        System.out.println(Vec_J.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Usuario").getAsString());
        if(P.getUsuario().equals(Vec_J.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Usuario").getAsString())){                       
            Condicion =  true;            
            
            break;
        }    
    }    
    return Condicion;
}
```